# index not reset to 0 after i get back to the page by the back key

Tags: javascript

Following is the script that makes a jump menu.Using javascript i have set the index of the `options` tag to be equal to 0.The scrip works fine except one.After i jump to another page from the jump menu the index is not reset to the index 0.Instead it is set to the index where i had clicked.Why is it so ? What is the problem with script ?

**script:**

```
window.onload = startInit;

function startInit() {
document.getElementById("newLocation").selectedIndex = 0;
document.getElementById("newLocation").onchange = jumpPage;
}

function jumpPage() {
var newLoc = document.getElementById("newLocation");
var newPage = newLoc.options[newLoc.selectedIndex].value;
if(newPage != "")
   window.location = newPage;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
<center>
<form>
<select id="newLocation">
 <option value="myworld.gif">first</option>
 <option value="myhome.gif">second</option>
 <option value="myroom.gif">third</option>
 <option value="mybed.jpg">fourth</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Browser acts smart and caches your page.* So are seeing the cached version of your
HTML page.To ensure that this doesn't happen and you always start up with the 
0th index,tell the browser not to do anything *(the way you want)* when the page 
unloads.

The statement should be:
`window.onunload = function(){}; // do nothing function`

you can add after `window.onload = startInit;`

That tells the browser that something happened during unloading and therefore it 
should re-read the page.

Comment: Yup, and/or you could add [zero/negative length expire headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211001/easiest-way-to-prevent-the-back-button-of-your-browser-from-showing-secure-data-a).