# How to stop the browser from going back to viewed pages after logout action?

Tags: javascript, jsf, browser, jsf-2, logout

I have Logout Link in the home page and on clicking that link I am redirecting user to the login page.

When user click on back in browser it redirecting to home page after loutout.

How to stop this.

I have tried using javascript code at the header of login page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function noBack() { window.history.forward() }
            noBack();
            window.onload = noBack;
            window.onpageshow = function (evt) { if (evt.persisted) noBack() }
            window.onunload = function () { void (0) }
</script>
```

Help me out here.

Comment: the best is to use location.replace(url) when navigating and having your application handle revisiting on the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [easiest way to prevent the back button of your browser from showing secure data after a user logs out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211001/easiest-way-to-prevent-the-back-button-of-your-browser-from-showing-secure-data)

Comment: You ll find answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid back button on JSF+Primefaces application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsfprimefaces-application)

Comment: Do not use JavaScript. That's plain stupid. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-previous-secured-page-after-logout/4194251#4194251